# Store a fixed value in the variable only once

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I have a variable in my code called p_fix. It is necessary to save the value of this variable when PE>p. But the way I did it, every time PE>p is respected, the value of this variable is changed, how can I save its value only once when PE>p and never change the value of this variable (p_fix) again?

```
for n = 1:size(t,1)
 if  n>=4
     X = [Ia(n-1,1) Ia(n-2,1) ; Ia(n-2,1) Ia(n-3,1)];
     future = [Ia(n,1) ; Ia(n-1,1)];
     C = X\future;
     Ia_future(n,1) = C(1,1)*Ia(n,1)+C(2,1)*Ia(n-1,1);
     PE(n,1)=Ia(n,1)+Ia_future(n,1);
     p(n,1)=(1+0.2)*max(PE(n-1,1));
     
 if  PE(n-1,1)>p(n,1)
     p_fix = p(n,1);

      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `for n = 1:size(t,1), if  n>=4` just do `for n = 4:size(t,1)`!

Comment: True, this way is smarter, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

1. Before the loop, initialize `p_fix` to an empty array, and only set it if it’s empty:

   ```matlab
   if isempty(p_fix) && PE(n-1,1)>p(n,1)
      p_fix = p(n,1);
   end
   ```
2. Or use a second Boolean variable, for example `done`, that keeps track of whether you’ve set your other variable or not. Initialize it to `false` before the loop, then:

   ```matlab
   if ~done && PE(n-1,1)>p(n,1)
      p_fix = p(n,1);
      done = true;
   end
   ```